# Mathmatical Average Calculation

Tags: python

Edit the program provided so that it receives a series of numbers from the user and allows the user to press the enter key to indicate that he or she is finished providing inputs. After the user presses the enter key, the program should print:

The Average and The Sum

I've been able to get it to print the sum of the numbers put in but I think it is messing up when trying to calculate the average. I really need some help with this. try inputting 100 59 37 21 and you will see what I mean

````
data = input("Enter a number: ") 
number = float(data)
while data != "":
    number = float(data)
    theSum += number
    data = input("Enter the next number: ")
print("The sum is", theSum)
average = theSum // number
print("The average is", average)```
````

Comment: Average is sum of values divided by count of values. Where are you tracking the count?

Comment: Keep a variable that has the total input count as value, and divide the sum with that.

Answer (score 0):

As Mat and Nagyl have pointed out in the comments you need to keep track of how many numbers were given and divide the sum by that to get the average

```
data = input("Enter a number: ")
number = float(data)
numbersGiven = 0
theSum = 0
while data != "":
    number = float(data)
    theSum += number
    numbersGiven += 1
    data = input("Enter the next number: ")
print("The sum is", theSum)
average = theSum / numbersGiven
print("The average is", average)
```

Notice that the first input isn't counted (I start with numbersGiven = 0) but the empty input at the end is counted so it gives the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these code too!
instead of writing the formula for average you can use statistics module

```
    import statistics
```

the code below asks you the numbers how many times you wrote in the number of datas

```
    number_of_datas=int(input("number of inputs asking: "))
    datas=[]
```

The following code takes the number from the number of times you wrote in the number of inputs
also you can write a Specified number instead of getting an input

```
    for i in range(number_of_datas):
        data = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        datas.append(data)
```

fmean is  float average

```
    average=statistics.fmean(datas)
    print(average)
```